# nwjs uri scheme internet explorer

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, uri, nwjs

I have an nwjs application for which I have registered a uri scheme in the registry. I have tried to change all user facing references to nwjs to the name of my application, so that the user knows that they are in the right place. However, I still get the following when attempting to launch from internet explorer:
[internet explorer nwjs launch from uri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSO8Y.png)

I can't find where that's set. (Firefox bases it off of the .exe's file description.)

Comment: Can provide registry entries to check issue?

Comment: Can you direct me to what I need to look at?